# how to authenticate valid user in nodejs and mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a problem in validating user name and password in nodejs and mongodb . Below is the code what i tried. Password validation not working. what i am doing wrong here...

```
server.get('/login', function(req, res)
{
var status=""
user.findOne({name: req.query.username}, function(err, users) 
{
    if( err || !users) 
    {
        console.log("No users found");
        status="failed"
    }   
    else 
    {
           if(password==req.query.password)
            {
                status="success"
            }
            else
            {
                status="failed"
            }
    }   

});
res.send(status);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js runs on an asynchronous [event loop](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-event-loop/), which means that your code won't necessary run the way you may always think it will (synchronously). To overcome this issue, there are a couple options: callbacks, or promises. Promises are generally the preferred route, and there are a couple libraries which I suggest: [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bluebird) (is awesome) or [async](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-async) (which I haven't used a lot, but many prefer it).

If you'd like to work without promises for right now, you could fix your issue this way:

```
user.findOne({name: req.query.username}, function(err, users) {
    if( !err && users && password === req.query.password ) {

        res.send({ status: 'success' });

    }

    else { res.send({ status: 'failed' }); }

});
```

Again, the reason your code is not working is because the event loop reaches your `res.send(status)` before the database query has been resolved. My suggestion should work fine for you, but as your processes become more complex, I would look into promises to resolve any further async issues.